# Newbie: How to get JSON/JQUERY to work

Tags: jquery, json

I have searched on google trying to learn how to use JSON and while it works when I simply copy/paste some of the examples as they are, despite numerous attempts I am having troubles using it for my own purposes.

Here is the code I am currently trying to use. Where are my errors?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>getJSON</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://hotell.difi.no/api/jsonp/brreg/enhetsregisteret?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query=987369396',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        document.write(response);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: "I am having troubles using it for my own purposes." what are your purposes? because copy/pasting some code wont figure out what you want

Comment: When I try to access the page, saved as a php.file on the server, I am not getting any output to the screen: blank page. I am trying to access the JSON-data and display it, here in its simplest form.

Comment: You are getting `parsererror` for your API call. Please have a look at the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hWHYX/24/) to check how to capturing errors for AJAX call.If you are also getting the same error then please `#1.` Update the title of the question. `#2.` Google more about `parsererror`. `#3.` Try changing your dataType as jsonp. `#4.` Update the body of your question.

Comment: Yes, where are your errors?  We need you to describe your problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX function should come after the DOM ready event, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://hotell.difi.no/api/jsonp/brre/enhetsregisteret?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&query=987369396',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            document.write(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: he forgot to put content into dom ready so it not works that solve